# Interpretation of regression analysis with integer value as response and predictor

Tags: regression

I have a data set of partygoers. For each partygoer I know which party she attended. I want to be able to estimate how many partygoers a pair of parties ($i, j$) *should* have in common *given* the number of participants of each of the two party.

The idea is to spot within the dataset pair of parties which have higher or lower shared partygoers than the average controlling for the size of both parties.

Let's be clear. I *do* know who went to which party. I *don't* want to predict something that is not in the dataset. What I *do want* to know is whether the number of shared participant by each pair of parties is far from the "average" of the dataset. But somehow I need to control for the size of the two parties because of course the higher the size the higher the chance to see people being in both parties.

I imagined a linear regression model like

PartygoersInCommon $\approx \beta_0 + \beta_1 ($Partygoers$_i$ Partygoers$_j)$

I have two questions concerning the interpretation of the results:

1) The fact that the response PartygoersInCommon is not a continuous variable but an integer does complicate the interpretation of the model?

2) Is it correct to multiply Partygoers$_i$ and Partygoers$_j$ or would be better to treat them as two separate independent variables like in

PartygoersInCommon $\approx \beta_0 + \beta_1$ Partygoers$_i + \beta_2$  Partygoers$_j$?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a regression problem at all. I'm not even sure it's a statistics problem. There is no uncertainty or stochastic element.

If you know which parties each person attended, then you can calculate exactly how many people were at any pair of parties. Let's take a simple example:

```
        Party 1    Party 2
Bob        X  
Bill       X          X
Jane                  X
Jill       X
```

How many people went to both party 1 and party 2? Only 1: Bill. With more parties it gets a little more complicated, but it never becomes a statistical problem.

Comment: What I want to get is a sort of benchmark value so to allow observations about real values. I want to be able to say: given the the number of people participating to party A and B is "odd" that just so few people participated to both because given the dataset I'd have expected to see more. If the parties were organised by the "Church of Satan" and the "Catholic Church" respectively I could use the response from my regression to estimate the difference from the expected value, so to say the number of missing persons... Does it make sense?

Comment: Ah, OK. But you still don't need regression. This could be handled by chi-square.

Comment: Are you saying that it is wrong to use a regression for this or that it is better to use chi-square?

Comment: It seems to me this becomes a statistical problem as soon as we clarify the sense of "predict" in the question.  For instance, suppose we observe the attendance at a party not in the dataset, party $n+1$. For each party $i$ in the dataset, $1\le i \le n,$ let us estimate how many people were at parties $i$ and $n+1$.  Is this what you meant by "predict," Francesco?  Whether or not it is, it would help if you could edit your question to clarify this point.

Comment: Francesco First, see @Whuber 's question; he has a different take on it, one I hadn't thought of. If you mean it his way, then he may have more advice. However, if your situation is more like the one I envision (that is, you  actually *know* who went to which party) then there is no dependent variable and hence no regression.

Comment: Sorry if the question is unclear. I *do* know who went to which party. I *don't* want to predict something that is not in the dataset. What I want to know is whether the number of shared participant by each pair of parties is far from the "average" of the dataset. But somehow I need to control for the size of the two parties because of course the higher the size the higher the chance to see people being in both parties.

Comment: Then chisquare does what you want.

Comment: @PeterFlom Could you offer an answer operationalise the use of chi-square with my example? I am not familiar with chi-square. How should I interpret the results in the terms of the expected number of common participants?

Comment: For each pair of parties you  would have an observed number (the number at both) and an expected number (number at one*number at other/total number of people). Then you can compute $\frac{(O-E)^2+}{E}$ and compare it to a $\chi^2$ critical value with df = number of pairs - 1